# How can I modify permissions on columns in an Excel table populated by a TFS query?

Tags: excel, tfs, permissions

I have exported Bug Work Items from TFS into an Excel table; how can I change the read-only permissions for the Symptom column information to Edit?

Answer (score 0):

The Symptom column is HTML, and we don't support editing HTML fields in Excel. See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/05/26/change-in-html-field-behavior-in-the-2010-tfs-excel-integration.aspx) for more information